# Styled Text into a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, nsattributedstring

We are currently building a Native IOS7 app.  Part of the brief requires a text view to be displayed which pulls styled text from a CMS database and displays it in a UITextView.

Is it possible to display styled text (ie HTML style bold, italic, listed elements) in a UIView and if so what format would it need to be delivered in to display correctly?

Comment: Here is an example using RTF but it could also use HTML  Implementing Rich Text with Images on OS X and iOS | OSSH
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *htmlString = // ...
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: would that display plain old HTML tags then?  sounds ideal

Comment: Yes, it supports HTML tags.